# How to use the As.Date function to also return the time?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a date column from my dataset in R. The variable, that has the date/time information is constructed as follows 2014-12-12 17:00:00.000. When I try to make a new date column with the following code,
`df$newdate <- as.Date(df$date)`, I only get a date column in the form year/month/day. I also want that my date column includes the hour of the day. How can I include this in my `newdate` column?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, if you want a data-time, use `as.POSIXct`. `as.Date` returns a date object (as its name already indicates).

Comment: You may want to try out package `lubridate`.